# Getting access to other windows using Java

Tags: java

Basically my idea is to develop a simple application using Java where the application runs in the background as a daemon but pops up a window when a hotkey is pressed. And that application accesses the content on the screen(like if a PDF doc is opened, the application should be able to access the content of the opened doc).

The application's behavior can be compared with a dictionary application where we usually select a text in any window and use a hotkey, and the dictionary shows the meaning of the selected text.

I am using [Jintellitype](http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/) to listen to the hotkey. But I have no idea how to get access to any other window's content. Because the application's behavior depends upon the content of the window, I'm stuck here. So, my question is whether is it possible to get the content of other windows(not like spyware of course), if yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "content"? The only thing always available is the picture you see on the screen. You can get it with [java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)).

Comment: yes, we can use Robot class to capture the screen. But how about the text as content if you are reading a document?

Comment: In fact, any hint on how a dictionary captures content would really be helpful.

Comment: Other then JNI, or the above mentioned methods there is no native Java API to do this for you, as a application may be written in c or c# etc thus, only using native Win32API calls would get the content of the window/component, even then not all components allow this